# JSTL: Iterate over a list with a foreign key

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have two tables in my database. `Cars` and `Customers`. In `Cars` table I have a foreign key column "`customer_id`". What I want to do is show Customer's name in a table of cars in a jsp page. I can iterate and show cars without problem. But when I want to show the owner of the car in a new column, don't know what to do! I have 2 attributes available in the view: List of `cars` and `customers`.

```
<c:forEach items="${cars}" var="car">
  <tr>
  <td><c:out value="${car.licencePlate}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${car.brand}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${car.model}" /></td>
  // I want to show here the owner of the car with help of
  // the customer_id (foreign key) in car table. How should I iterate?
  <td><c:out value="${customers.name}" /></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This is the method in the controller class

```
@RequestMapping("/allCars")
public String displayAll(Model model) {

    List<Car> cars = carRepository.findAll();
    List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("cars", cars);
    model.addAttribute("customers", customers);

    return "/car/display_all";
}
```

Comment: Better to use a ORM framework like Hibernate or JPA to do it easily.

Comment: I recommend you to obtain the proper data from a Servlet or another server based technology like Spring `@Controller` or JSF managed bean, add the data as request attribute and in the view just access to it freely. In this case, seems like you're using `<sql>` tag which is not appropriated for real world apps.

Comment: I am using Spring, `@Controller` but don't know how to solve this problem :( @Luiggi Mendoza, I don't use slq datasource (if that what's you are referring to) by the way. Everything is annotation based.

Comment: @Masud I am using `JPA` but still don't know how to solve my problem :)

Comment: Then provide how you create this `cars` and `customers` in your `@Controller` to provide more accurate help. The more we know about your problem, the easier it's for us to help you.

Comment: I added the related method in the controller class

Comment: It will be better if you recover the `cars` and the `customers` already associated in a single query rather than trying to tie them in application. I guess you're using Hibernate but don't have an association between car and customer, or you do?

Comment: No association between them. I have only a foreign key in cars table that I fixed in mysql workbench. Nothing else.

Comment: @oxyt that's your problem. If a car has a customer, you should have a ManyToOne association from car to customer. You could then use car.getCustomer().getName() or, in the view ${car.customer.name}.

Comment: @JBNizet it's working now. Thank you for your comment. But I would love to mark your comment as correct answer if you use "Answer question". Thanx again!